# z-index stacking order issue

Tags: css, z-index

I've checked the answers to all the similar questions here and searched the web - I've read all the tutorials on stacking order - but I still have a problem.
I want to stack an element on top of another element but can't make it stack the way I want.
Here's the basic HTML and CSS structure of the elements:

```css
#element-1{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2 !important;
}
#element-2{
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='element-1'>
   <p>stuff in here</p>
</div>
<div id='element-2'>
   <p>stuff in here2</p>
</div>
```

So, as you can see, I'm trying to stack element-1 on top of element-2 but it just won't do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "stack on top of". You mean on top of with regard to the z-plane? Or with regard to the y-plane?

Comment: In terms of the z plane

Comment: So, I seem to have fixed the issue by removing the z-index from element-2. I must have needed it for something when I first made the site but I don't seem to need it now. I had to make some revisions to the site. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You know you've taken a wrong turn when `!important` feels necessary.

Comment: What happens if you set the second element to have `position: absolute` as in both examples?

Comment: The second element still displays in front of the first element. Can't figure out why. I tried everything I could think of, but it always stayed that way, until I changed the z-index on the second element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this is strange:

Set the z-index on 'element-2' to 0.

This is an odd problem, and probably won't come up for anyone else, but I'll go through it anyway.

I had set the z-index for 'element-2' to 1 because I needed it on the desktop version of the site. It has links inside it and the links didn't work without the z-index. Later I needed to make revisions to the site and while making the changes I checked the pop out navigation menu on the mobile version of the site - which is 'element-1' - and it wouldn't sit in front of 'element-2'. I just checked the site again and when I set the z-index for 'element-2' to 1 it sits in front of 'element-1'. If I delete the z-index for 'element-2' completely it won't work correctly on the desktop version, so the work around for this particular issue is:

```
#element-2{
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

CSS [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top), [left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left), [background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) are only for demonstration purposes.

`#element-1` above `#element-2` orange is above green cause of higher z-index

```css
#element-1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;

    /* next properties are only for demonstration purposes but not needed */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}
#element-2{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
 
     /* next properties are only for demonstration purposes but not needed */
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='element-1'>
    <p>stuff in here</p>
</div>
<div id='element-2'>
    <p>stuff in here</p>
</div>
```

`#element-2` above `#element-1` green is above orange cause of higher z-index

```css
#element-1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

    /* next properties are only for demonstration purposes but not needed */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}
#element-2{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2;
 
     /* next properties are only for demonstration purposes but not needed */
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='element-1'>
    <p>stuff in here</p>
</div>
<div id='element-2'>
    <p>stuff in here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried setting the opacity for e-1 to 0.99 and for e-2 to 0.5 but no good. They still stack in reverse.

Comment: @tdrsam sorry opacity was only here for demonstration purposes. opacity just sets a "transparency" to the element. See the updated answer you have to stack with `z-index`

Comment: So the key is setting the overlapping element to `absolute`?

Comment: No the key is `z-index` but if you don't `position: absolute` the elements are next to each other and not above each other. So in this case if setting `position: relative;` the `z-index` would have no effect. [Read more (all) about positioning here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: 1/ `z-index` has an effect as soon as an element is _positioned_ (set to fixed, absolute, relative or I guess sticky. Not positioned with default value of static) but you won't see it till this element has (in the X-Y plane) a chance to be on top or bottom of another. `position: absolute` achieves this and `transform: translate(-10px, -10px);` too. 2/ background-color and opacity are useful way of having a chance to see what is happening (as the MDN article about z-index does).